# How to trigger one element inside a div on mouse hover in CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I have a square image of 220px by 220px (*myimage.jpg*). In the right corner of the image, I have a grey triangle created using CSS (*triangle-topright*) and on top of that, a small png icon (my_icon.png). I am looking to get a transition 0.5sec from grey(#c3c2c0) to blue (#014792) of the triangle (and only the triangle) using CSS triggered when the user puts his mouse pointer over ANY portion of the 220px by 220px image. Is there any way to accomplish that using strictly CSS?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="category-image">
    <i class="triangle-topright"><i></i></i>
    <img src="my_icon.png" class="icon-png-over"/>
    <img src="my_image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.category-image {
    position: relative;
}

.icon-png-over {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 190;
}

.triangle-topright {
    position: relative;
}

.triangle-topright > i {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 32px solid transparent;
    border-right: 32px solid #c3c2c0;
    border-top: 32px solid #c3c2c0;
    left: 156;
    top: 14;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `.category-image` is the same size as the image, you can use:

```
.category-image:hover .triangle-topright > i {
    border-right: 32px solid #014792;
    border-top: 32px solid #014792;
}
```

Then for the transition, just add the properties to the `i` element: (Vendor prefixes omitted for brevity.)

```
.triangle-topright > i {
    transition: border 0.5s linear;
}
```

You might also need to change the `display` of `.category-image` to `inline-block` in order to shrink to fit the image's dimensions.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t2e7obe/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the only problem I have now is that my triangle seems to be placed at the proper position when loading the page but as soon as I hover, it slides about 10px-20px down and stays there.

Comment: @LaGuille That's odd. Do you mind making an example demonstrating this? It doesn't do that in the one I posted.

Comment: Removing `top:14` solved the problem. Everything is perfect now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what you want. However, try this code for your css

```
    .category-image {
         position:relative;
    }
   .icon-png-over {
         position:absolute;
         top:10;
         left:190;
   }
   .triangle-topright {
         position: relative;
   }
   .triangle-topright > i {
         position: absolute;
         width: 0;
         height: 0;
         line-height: 0;
         border: 32px solid transparent;
         border-right: 32px solid #c3c2c0;
         border-top: 32px solid #c3c2c0;
         left: 156;
         top: 14;
         -webkit-transition: border 0.5s ease;
         -moz-transition: border 0.5s ease;
         -o-transition: border 0.5s ease;
         transition: border 0.5s ease;
   }
  .triangle-topright > i:hover {
        border-right:  32px solid #014792;
        border-top:  32px solid #014792;
   }
```

i hope this will help
cheers